# How to use two different designs for web and mobile

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, web

I would like to be able to have a certain design for my web page, and when resized to mobile, use a different design. I will include photos to better explain.

Here is the design that i would like to use for 
[Web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUUax.png)
And here is the sketch for
[Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyc0Q.png)
I am not completely sure how to use media queries at the moment
Here is the code so far

HTML
        
            
                Infants
            
            
                Children 2+

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="full-time col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-2">Full Time</div>
        <div class="prices-left-box col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-5">
            <div class="prices-left">$200 Per Week</div>
        </div>
        <div class="prices-right-box col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-5">
            <div class="prices-right">$150 Per Week</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="full-time col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-2">Up to 4 Hours</div>
        <div class="prices-left-box col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-5">
            <div class="prices-left">$125 Per Week</div>
        </div>
        <div class="prices-right-box col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-5">
            <div class="prices-right">$100 Per Week</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .infants{
        color: black;
        background-color: #7FC7AF;
        font-size: 36px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: "open sans";
        height: 125px;
        width: 304.3px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .children{
        color: black;
        background-color: #FF9E9D;
        font-size: 36px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-family: "open sans";
        height: 125px;
        width: 304.4px;
        text-align: center;
        padding: auto;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}

.infants{
    color: white;
    background-color: #7FC7AF;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "open sans";
    height: 87px;
    width: 304.3px;
    text-align: center;
}

.infants-box{
    padding-left: 176px;
    padding-right: 80px;
}

.children{
    color: white;
    background-color: #FF9E9D;
    font-size: 36px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "open sans";
    height: 87px;
    width: 304.4px;
    text-align: center;
}

.payment-method{
    font-size: 24px;
    padding-bottom: 57px;
    padding-top: 57px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "Source Sans Pro";
    font-weight: 600;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 30px;
    color: #4B4B4B
}

.full-time{
    background-color: #454545;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "open sans";
    height: 150px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 176px;
    text-align: center;
}
.prices-left-box{
    background-color: white;
    width: 304.4px;
    height: 150px;
}
.prices-left{
    font-family: "source sans pro";
    font-size: 24px;
    width: 304.3px;
    margin-right: 220px;
    text-align: center;
}

.prices-right-box{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 304.4px;
    margin-left: 10%;
    height: 150px
}

.prices-right{
        font-family: "source sans pro";
    font-size: 24px;
    background color: white !important;
    text-align: center;
}
.background-pricing{
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
    padding-bottom: 84px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be it that you're using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), just reference the [grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) and apply changes to your class names as referenced. You can also see these [Responsive Utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) in the docs:

If you do need to use the code above, try rewriting your above snippet like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .infants{
           /* 
           Custom CSS here 
           ...
           */
     }
}
```

Comment: Would I need to create a completely new html for mobile? I tried playing with the grids, but it threw the design all over the place

Comment: Bootstrap's default is for extra small screens. `col-xs-12`, etc. Try starting from the phone and working up to larger screens. You certainly shouldn't need to create totally different HTML (most of the time). You'll just need to change some some grid classes.

Comment: Also try using `offset`, i.e. `col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-4` to center your content

Comment: Would I need to create separate rows for mobile? or does bootstrap automatically stack everything? (Thanks for being patient, haha)

Comment: np, bootstrap will stack it for mobile without a new row

Comment: I got it working. I ended up going a totally different direction, but without the need to use the offset attribute. Here is a small album of what it looks like online http://imgur.com/gallery/owGF2  Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out the documentation on http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid and [Bootstrap Responsive Utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) to create a responsive layout that stacks your row grid structure for smaller mobile screens.

I would recommend building your layout first for mobile instead of desktop. Work on getting your mobile layout correct with the `.col-xs-*`, then move onto Tablet size with `.col-sm-*`, larger tablets and desktops with `.col-md-*` and finally Large devices Desktops with `.col-lg-*`. See this code pen for a good example of the options - http://codepen.io/arsinak/pen/qDgvt/

> Use the extra small and medium device grid classes by adding .col-xs-* .col-md-* to your columns. [Example: Mobile and desktop](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed).

You won't need to define media queries within your own css for your containers and grid system, bootstrap handles this. If you need to define CSS based off media queries. I would recommend creating your CSS for mobile first then scale out depending on screen size.

```
/*==========  Mobile First Method  ==========*/

/* Custom, iPhone Retina */
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px){

}

/* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px){

}

/* Small Devices, Tablets */
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px){

}

/* Medium Devices, Desktops */
@media only screen and (min-width : 992px){

}

/* Large Devices, Wide Screens */
@media only screen and (min-width : 1200px){

}
```

Also to cleanup your CSS and reduce repeated code I would suggest using [SASS](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2014/08/5-reasons-you-should-be-using-sass-today/) along with the [BEM Methodology](https://mindtheshift.wordpress.com/2014/10/15/getting-the-best-out-of-bem-with-sass/) to structure your css in a clearer way that is easy to understand and maintain.